# undefined method using Capybara drag_to method

Tags: capybara

I wish to use the capybara method drag_to in order to manually sort items on a page.     Below is my code:

```
pos2 = find('#first_element')
target = find(#second_element)
pos2.drag_to(target)
```

However I get the error message:

```
undefined method `drag_to' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Am I invoking the method incorrectly? I am attempting to implement as defined here: http://rubydoc.info/gems/capybara/0.4.0/Capybara/Element#drag_to-instance_method

Please note I am able to use other capybara methods fill_in, visit etc without any problems...

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The exception says that `pos2` is nil. That suggests you are not finding the first element correctly. It might help to show your actual code.

Comment: Could you please add your actual code? It's obvious that provided snippet wouldn't work since there is typo. There should be `find('#second_element')` instead of `find(#second_element)`

Comment: @Justin - Thanks, you were right, I was not finding the first element. I changed it so that it now uses xpath so my code is:                                                             `pos2 = find(:xpath, '//*[@id="people_container"]/div[1]/img')
  target = find(:xpath, '//*[@id="people_container"]/div[3]/img')
  pos2.drag_to(target)`                                                This does not cause an error but the elements are not moved. :-(

Answer (score 0):

`#drag_to` actually won't move sortable elements, since you're not moving it "to" anywhere as much as a set distance in a certain direction. Selenium implements `#drag_by` but it is not yet supported by Capybara.

See also:

https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/issues/222

https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/issues/119